# PHP mcrypt usage class?

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I'm pretty new at this. Tried to make sense of the manual page for mcrypt at PHP.net when I thought a good tutorial would do a better job. So I searched yet without anything substantial.

I also tried one of the examples of using mcrypt to perform the encryption and decryption with 2 functions, but it gives a warning of "Size of key is too large for this algorithm".

Can anyone please write me a two-way class to do the encryption / decryption using mcrypt so I can make sense of the library? Thanks!

Comment: How about asking for help with the library, instead of asking us to do work for you? If you want an open-source bit of software done without doing it yourself, you can at least offer to pay: http://nextsprocket.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See this SO thread: [PHP Mcrypt - Encrypting / Decrypting file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448256/php-mcrypt-encrypting-decrypting-file/2448441#2448441)

FYI, it's very uncool to ask people to do your work for you. At least show an effort. We're here to help, not be slave labor.