# encrypting and decrypting information stored in cookies

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I need to securely crypt and decrypt information about users (`user_id` and `password`) in cookies.

What is the best way to do this ? What encryption and decryption functions do I need ?

I'm using `PHP` and `MySQL` and example will be participated ?

Comment: storing password in cookie is not recommended

Comment: Why do you *need* to store user passwords in a cookie?

Comment: because POST data can be sniff so i thought using cookie with encryption to send login credentials would be better wt u suggest ?

Comment: Whats wrong letting the user enter their password. If you want a 'remember me' system you can sort some sort of token in a cookie. Storing passwords in a cookie is a huge security issue.

Comment: Use ssl to protect your posted data then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I encrypt a cookie value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648440/how-can-i-encrypt-a-cookie-value)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't store passwords in a cookie. Never do this kind of things.
If you want some way for you user to not have to enter its login and password to login, you can genrate some random token when he logs in (`sha1(mt_rand())` for example) and store this value in the cookie and database.

Then when trying to identify a user, you just have to check if the value found in his cookie can be found in your database. Generate a new value everytime he logs in (using name + password or with this cookie).

Answer (score 16):

for example

```
Set encrypted cookie:
<?php

$time = time()+60*60*24*30*12; //store cookie for one year
setcookie('cookie_name', encryptCookie('cookie_value'),$time,'/');

?>

Get encrypted cookie value:

<?php

$cookie_value = decryptCookie($_COOKIE['cookie_name']);

?>
```

here is the function to encrypt decrypt cookie:

```
    <?php

function encryptCookie($value){
   if(!$value){return false;}
   $key = 'The Line Secret Key';
   $text = $value;
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
   $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
   return trim(base64_encode($crypttext)); //encode for cookie
}

function decryptCookie($value){
   if(!$value){return false;}
   $key = 'The Line Secret Key';
   $crypttext = base64_decode($value); //decode cookie
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
   $decrypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $crypttext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
   return trim($decrypttext);
}

?>
```

You can read more about the mcrypt function here:
[php mcrypt function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)

Comment: Could you define the function `encryptCookie()`?

Comment: @Michiel: I'd be far more interested in decryptCookie() if he's going to use MD5.

Comment: sorry, was a little fast there. i have added the encrypt /decrypt examples now

Comment: @Michael: That's funny (and interesting)! @Mikelangelo: Where are you using MD5?

Comment: @Michael: I could not decode to get the original message if the original message has special characters: $value="adsj+adf%B3==". Not sure whether that's related to this topic, but I can't the cookie is set good but the $_COOKIE['mycookie'] does not have these special chars. Thanks.

Comment: mcrypt_encrypt(): Key of size 19 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of sizes 16, 24 or 32 supported

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to "securely crypt and decrypt information about users in cookies" because storing that information in cookies is inherently insecure.

The recommended technique is to generate a random session identifier and use that as the **only** piece of information stored in cookies.  This session id is then used on the server side to look up the user's actual account information (and any state regarding what they're doing) in a database or file so that you're only sending a small amount of otherwise meaningless data back and forth across the network with each request made by the user.  If such a cookie is intercepted by The Bad Guys, it will only compromise the user's session (allowing the attacker to temporarily impersonate the user until the session is ended); the user's password will remain secure because it is not in the cookie and (presumably) is not ever displayed on any page of your application.