# PHP redirect holding up script

Tags: php, redirect

**UPDATE**

I found the issue that was holding up my script.  Apparently it had nothing to do with decryption, but my redirect instead.  When I removed this block of code, the script starting performing quickly.  Still not sure why this was causing the issue?

```
// Make sure we have an Order ID
if( ! isset($_GET['id']) && ! isset($_POST['id']) ) {
    header("Location: https://www.website.com/orders/");
    exit;
}
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have been using the Encryption class found here: [Encryption class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448256/php-mcrypt-encrypting-decrypting-file/2448441#2448441).  I am storing the data in a MySQL database, with a VARCHAR binary data type (formerly I tried BLOB and TINYBLOB).

The encrypting and decrypting both work, however it takes like 1 minute to decrypt.  The encryption is fast.

I guess I should also say that this is happening over a https connection (in case that's relevant).

I don't remember it always taking this long to decrypt.  Do you have any idea what could be causing this?  When I comment out the decryption portion of the PHP code, and just echo back the encrypted string, it performs quickly.

**CODE AS REQUESTED BELOW IN THE COMMENTS**

```
class Encryption
{
    const CYPHER = 'blowfish';
    const MODE   = 'cfb';
    const KEY    = 'MyPersonalKey';

    public function encrypt($plaintext)
    {
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(self::CYPHER, '', self::MODE, '');
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, self::KEY, $iv);
        $crypttext = mcrypt_generic($td, $plaintext);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        return $iv.$crypttext;
    }

    public function decrypt($crypttext)
    {
        $plaintext = '';
        $td        = mcrypt_module_open(self::CYPHER, '', self::MODE, '');
        $ivsize    = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);
        $iv        = substr($crypttext, 0, $ivsize);
        $crypttext = substr($crypttext, $ivsize);
        if ($iv)
        {
            mcrypt_generic_init($td, self::KEY, $iv);
            $plaintext = mdecrypt_generic($td, $crypttext);
        }

        return $plaintext;
    }
}
```

Here is the code from the webpage, where I set the variables from the MySQL row.  I am using WordPress' $wpdb object.

```
$order = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = ".$order_id." LIMIT 0,1");

$addons_price =      $order->addons_price;
$hooked_package =    (isset($_GET['hooked_package'])) ? $_GET['hooked_package'] : $order->hooked_package;
$arrival_date_unix = $order->arrival_date_unix;
$order_data =        unserialize($order->order_data);
$preview_total =     $order_data['preview_price'] + $addons_price + $order_data['travel_insurance'];
$normal_total =      $order_data['normal_price'] + $addons_price + $order_data['travel_insurance'];
$package_price =     $order->package_price;
$total_price =       $order->total_price;
$billing_cc =        Encryption::decrypt($order->billing_cc);
```

Also, here is the MySQL type...

```
`billing_cc` varbinary(255) DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the code, particularly a few lines before and after the "decryption" process?

Comment: Try adding and then moving a  "die('stopped on line x')" statement at each line of your decrypt function. Move that down the function until you isolate exactly which mcrypt call is slow.

Comment: I cannot see any problem in that class, do you have a really long key? This could be a factor for slow decrypting

Comment: The key is 15 characters long

Comment: I'm thinking that the delay is actually happening somewhere else in my script, not during the decrypt phase.  I'll keep posting.

Comment: Found the issue.  Still doesn't make sense to me.  I added it towards the top of my question.  Thanks everyone for helping me out.  Michael Petrov, your die() suggestion is what eventually saved the day in debugging.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The code you indicate as being your problem is a simple conditional redirect. So it shouldn't have anything to do with the decryption. The only reason I can see for the redirect being slow is that the web server is under heavy load, on a slow connection or has some other performance issue.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the confusion.  I understand what the code means.  However, I have found that the decryption was NOT the cause of the lag after all.  Once I removed the redirect block of code, the script ran fast.  Not sure why.