# What is the best way to encrypt files in AES-256 with PHP?

Tags: php, security, encryption

I found some tutorials online that could help but I am not sure there the best options. I would like to encrypt the file with a highly secure algorithm (I am a bit paranoid) but at the same time I am looking for speed (I know it's a bit of a contradiction)... So I chose AES-256... But what is the best way to use AES-256 with PHP to encrypt files?

Comment: Do you want to encrypt/decrypt with the same key/password, or do you want this to be asymmetric?

Comment: I want encrypt/decrypt with the same key/password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### PHP 5.x and 7.0.x

For a symmetric algorithm, use [Mcrypt](http://php.net/mcrypt).

Note though that it can be risky, from a security perspective, to use that library without knowing what everything does. Take a look at some [ready-made solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448256/php-mcrypt-encrypting-decrypting-file/2448441#2448441).

(Incidentally, the ciphers supported are [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php)).

### PHP 7.1.x+

The Mcrypt extension was deprecated in 7.1 and removed in 7.2, so you will need an alternative. Use [Sodium](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sodium.php) instead.

Comment: Whatever you do, just don't use the mode MCRYPT_MODE_ECB.  Always use a non-ECB mode, and randomly-generated salt.

Comment: Thanks @slashingweapon. Out of interest, why should that mode be avoided?

Comment: **The short version:** If you encrypt plaintext X in ECB with the same salt every time, you always get the same output.  This equals very weak security.  **The long version:** [Applied Cryptography](http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Cryptography-Protocols-Algorithms-ebook/dp/B000SEHPK6/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1)

Comment: Heh, I'm sure that's a fine book, but libraries such as Mcrypt should be simple enough to use without reading _War And Peace_ `;-)`

Comment: That's why I gave you the short answer.

Answer (score -2):

PHP Mcrypt file based symmetric encryption with AES-256, (storing IV as first 16 bytes of file), and using sha256 hmac for authenticated encryption:

```
<?php
print_r(mcrypt_list_algorithms());//check if rijndael-128 available
print_r(stream_get_filters());    //should contain mcrypt.* and mdecrypt.*

//16 byte key=>AES-128, 24 byte key=>AES-192, 32 byte key=>AES-256
$key='BkK8Jts................sPo38nNcW';

//encrypt file
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);//or MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM
$fin = fopen($in_filename, "rb");
$fcrypt = fopen($aes_filename, 'wb');
fwrite($fcrypt, $iv);
$opts = array('iv'=>$iv, 'key'=>$key, 'mode'=>'cbc');
stream_filter_append($fcrypt, 'mcrypt.rijndael-128', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts);
while (!feof($fin))
{
    fwrite($fcrypt, fread($fin, 8192));
}
fclose($fcrypt);
fclose($fin);
$hmac_real = hash_hmac_file('sha256', $aes_filename, $key, $raw=false);

//decrypt file
$hmac_calc = hash_hmac_file('sha256', $aes_filename, $key, $raw=false);
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$fcrypt = fopen($aes_filename, "rb");
$fout = fopen($out_filename, 'wb');
$iv = fread($fcrypt, $iv_size);
$opts = array('iv'=>$iv, 'key'=>$key, 'mode'=>'cbc');
stream_filter_append($fcrypt, 'mdecrypt.rijndael-128', STREAM_FILTER_READ, $opts);
while (!feof($fcrypt))
{
    $block = fread($fcrypt, 8192);
    $block = feof($fcrypt)? rtrim($block,"\0") : $block;//removes aes pad
    fwrite($fout, $block);
}
fclose($fout);
fclose($fcrypt);
$hmac_calc==$hmac_real or unlink($out_filename);//invalid if they don't match
```

see: http://php.net/manual/en/filters.encryption.php

AES-256 has a known weakness, so you can use a 16 byte key to trigger AES-128 in this code
see: https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/another_new_aes.html

Comment: AES-256 is **not** "Rijndael 256". The 256 for Rijndael refers to the blocksize which is set to 128-bit in AES for every keysize available (128, 192, 256). Use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` for AES compatibility instead.

Comment: Working example of AES-256 (not Rijndael-256) in PHP: http://blog.turret.io/the-missing-php-aes-encryption-example/