# Emailing large encrypted email to Outlook client

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

This is somewhat of a complex question. I've been trying to implement a system where a user fills out their account information on a form and then it emails this information to a client. I have my php script which generates the email as a whole; however, when I use a function like openssl_public_encrypt, it fails. I've realized there is a length limit on this function?

I suppose my question is: "How do I encrypted a large email in php and then send that file to someone using an outlook client?"

Does anyone have any good information on this subject? It's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of information about the limits of `openssl_public_encrypt()` in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php). Check the comments, especially the one by Thomas Horsten.

My suggestion would be to use something like the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448256/php-mcrypt-encrypting-decrypting-file) - [Encrypting / Decrypting file with Mcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448256/php-mcrypt-encrypting-decrypting-file), store it on a server, and send a link to the user in email. If necessary, require a username and password to download the file.