# What security measures can I take to secure passwords that can't be hashed in a database?

Tags: python, mysql, hash, passwords

I'm making a company back-end that should include a password-safe type feature. Obviously the passwords needs to be plain text so the users can read them, or at least "reversible" to plain text somehow, so I can't use hashes.

Is there anything more *secure* I can do than just placing the passwords in plain-text into the database?

---

*Note: These are (mostly) auto-generated passwords that is never re-used for anything except the purpose they are saved for, which is mostly FTP server credentials.*

Comment: Real question: why do you need them to be reversible? You can't just autogenerate a new password for a user if they forget it? (is there some security rationale here?)

Comment: @JeffTratner: They must be reversible because this is a password-safe. It's a feature for saving passwords to the FTP servers of clients.

Comment: thanks for explaining :) I do feel a little silly for not understanding what a password-safe was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use encryption. The passwords won't be in plain text so you'll have some security but it can be reversed.

The code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2448441/250259) should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL's `ENCODE()`, `DES_ENCRYPT()` or `AES_ENCRYPT()` functions, and store the keys used to encrypt in a secure location.