# How to add extra data at the end of downloading content in PHP

Tags: php

I am developing a security for my downloadable contents simply securing my download content like this.

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Now I simply want to add 100 extra bytes (my custom details about that download file as per each download)

I want some way to add these 100 bytes after readfile($file); so downloaded file will have this extra information in it.

```
something like 
readfile($file) + myBytes()
```

I am new to PHP so please help me

Comment: This depends on the type of file you're downloading. Simply pasting extra bytes to the end of a file may render it effectively corrupt.

Comment: Maybe you should consider an encryption method with a secure key instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448256/php-mcrypt-encrypting-decrypting-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your extra bytes in a file,variable,db or etc , and echo it after read file function

```
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    readfile("extra_filename.ext");
    /* 
    //or use this
    $extra_bytes = "store extra bytes here";
    echo $extra_bytes;
    */
    exit;
}
```

Comment: As simple as that – thanks to you to save my time
Now I have developed my solution and my .net downloadable application is using this additional information for license verification

Comment: You need to add the length of the extra bytes to the Content-Length header as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only dealing with images, I'd recommend using [`steganography`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) instead of just pasting bytes to the end of a file. Googling "php steganography library" turns up a few hits:

- [steghide](http://steghide.sourceforge.net/)
- [phpstegano](http://code.google.com/p/phpstegano/)

Comment: I already have implemented steganography in Matlab but this is just a sample code from php.net actually my content is executer file which use this added information for license.