# Change the way to call a function from this :: to this ->

Tags: php, function, call

This is the thing... I have a simple class with some functions but I need to change the way that I call those functions.

Originally the class look like this

```
<?php
class Bcrypt {

const DEFAULT_WORK_FACTOR = 8;

public static function hash($password, $work_factor = 0) { ... }

public static function check($password, $stored_hash, $legacy_handler = NULL) { ... }

}?>
```

Now I need change the way that model call this class

Originally the model look like this

```
Bcrypt::hash($data['password'])
```

What I need to do is change this call to be like this:

```
$this->bcrypt->hash($data['password'])
```

I know maybe this is a simple question but I need to clarify some concepts...

Comment: Why can't you do this : $this->bcrypt::hash($data['password']);

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448256/php-mcrypt-encrypting-decrypting-file/2448441#2448441

Comment: do you really know what these operators mean?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: *(related)* [What does that symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: then read @Gordon's link

Answer (score 3):

Make your functions non-static.

And do some reading on classes and objects. In order to use ->, you will have to instantiate your class.

Comment: I just try that but I get:
Fatal error: Call to a member function hash() on a non-object in

Comment: That's the instantiation part. You need to create an object on which to call your methods first. This is absolutely basic OO-programming, so you should at least read up a bit on this.
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt();

Answer (score 1):

It's sounds you don't know the difference between public and static.

Static means that you do not need an instance to call a function like you do.

If you want to use the arrows, you need to make your functions public and make an instance first.

What you must do:

//create instance of the class first

```
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt();
```

//call the instance variable and choose your function

```
$bcrypt->hash($data['password']);
```

It is very important that you know the difference between static and public.
I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the function call is determined by the function being `static` or not, so the direct answer is "remove the `static` keyword from the function declaration".

However, a method being `static` or not should never be a matter of *preference*; it should be a *design decision*. You don't say why you need to make this change, there is nothing in the posted code that provides a relevant hint, and in this case it seems perfectly OK for the methods to be `static` in the first place.

So that leaves open the question: **why do you ask?**

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways in which you can call a method or a variable.

Static variables/methods from outside a class

```
 class Test {
    public static function testFunc() {}
 }

 Test::testFunc();
```

Static variables/methods from inside a class

```
class Test {
    public static function testFunc() {}
    public static function testFromInside() {
        return self::testFunc(); // you can do this with Test::testFunc() as well
    }
}

Test::testFromInside();
```

Non static variables from inside the class

```
class Test {
    public $test;
    public function testFunc() {
         return $this->test;
    }
}

$test = new Test;
$test->test;
$test->testFunc();
```

If it's unclear, let me know and I'll try to explain better.

Comment: Ok.. I read about but.. I'm a little frustated.. Some people seems to be born knowing this kind of things but I dont.. coul you give me more explicit guide to do this??