# mcrypt_decrypt wrong output after using encrypted data php

Tags: php, aes

I have a small problem with php `mcrypt_decrypt` function. Firstly, I use a 16-byte string, and encrypt it using `mcrypt_encrypt`; then, I use `base64_encode`, and put the output to `mcrypt_decrypt`, in order to get the initial string.

But the output is not what's expected. I checked that my `base64` decoded string input for decoding is the exact output produced by `mcrypt_decrypt`. Here is my code:

```
//encrypt
$str="KKQT9W4st7vmdkps";
$key="43625A8C1E4330BDF84DDEE3DD105037";
$block = mcrypt_get_block_size('rijndael_128', 'ecb');
$passcrypt=mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
echo $passcrypt;
```

That outputs `PTfZ6Ephh8LTxXL4In33Og==`. The decryption script is the following:

```
//decrypt
$str='PTfZ6Ephh8LTxXL4In33Og==';
$key='43625A8C1E4330BDF84DDEE3DD105037';
$str = base64_decode($str);
$str = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,
    $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,''),"\0");
$block = mcrypt_get_block_size('rijndael_128', 'ecb');
echo $str;
```

And the output is not `KKQT9W4st7vmdkps`, but `-nγ kk7Ζn’T` instead. Any ideas? I'm using XAMPP and Apache server.

Comment: Take a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448256/php-mcrypt-encrypting-decrypting-file

Answer (score 1):

Thx guys for the feedback it was a silly mistake that i made...actually 'PTfZ6Ephh8LTxXL4In33Og==' was wrong in the decrypt function cause "I" was "l" in the end...so the decryption was not correct...but it was not my fault either since I was getting this string from a QR CODE scanner and both "I" and "l" are displayed the same...

Answer (score 0):

For encryption, you need to:

1) Create an encryption resource

```
$str = "KKQT9W4st7vmdkps";
$key = "43625A8C1E4330BDF84DDEE3DD105037";
$r = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '',MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, '');
```

2) Randomly create encryption vector based on the size of `$r`

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($r),MCRYPT_RAND);
```

3) Initiliazing module using the resource,key and string vector

```
mcrypt_generic_init($r,$key,$iv);
```

4) Encrypt data/string using resource `$r`

```
$encrypted = mcrypt_generic($r,$str);
```

5) Encode it using `base64_encode`

```
  $encoded = base64_encode($encrypted);
        if(!mcrypt_generic_deinit($r) || !mcrypt_module_close($r))
            $encoded = false;
```

6) Echoing it

```
echo 'Encrypted: '.$encoded;
```

For decryption, it's like a reverse process of encrypt

```
        //Using the same enrypted string       
        $decoded = (string) base64_decode(trim($encoded));
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '',MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, '');
        $ivs = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
        mcrypt_generic_init($td,$key, $ivs);

        $decoded = (string) trim(mdecrypt_generic($td, $decoded));

        if(!mcrypt_generic_deinit($td) || !mcrypt_module_close($td))
            $decoded = false;
```

Echoing it

```
echo 'Decrypted: '. $decoded;
```

Hope this helps. More info [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php).

Comment: The result is still the same..."-nγ kk7Ζn’T"...i think that the problem is not the code but the output format..maybe apache, i don't know...

Comment: I've edited the answer,the decryption part.. try it out again.

Comment: Thx the issue is solved...it was a mistake when I was passing the string 'PTfZ6Ephh8LTxXL4In33Og=='to aes decrypt.... "I" was "l" actually but since i was getting this from a QR CODE SCANNER i couldn't tell the difference cause "I" and "l" are displayed the same there...stupid really...