# After modifying my .htaccess file to hide the .php extension from the URL, some directory items are unable to be found

Tags: php, .htaccess

Recently, I got some help modifying my .htaccess file to hide the .php extension in the url. After I got it working, a few bugs occurred with my site. For whatever reason, any php page in a sub directory returns a 404 error. For example:

> mywebsite.com/test/test.php (this 404's)

but

> mywebsite.com/test/test.html (this works just fine)

Since this only started occurring after my .htaccess file was modified, I am assuming the problem lies there. The file contains as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+?\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

If there is any more information I can provide to help solve this, please let me know!

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php    
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+?\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! I am so thoroughly impressed with your knowledge on something that I am can hardly grasp. A thousand thank you's, I really appreciate you taking the time to help! Best wishes

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. http://askapache.com is pretty good resource on .htaccess in case you're going to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intended to hide your PHP project structure to be accessed by public as directory tree ... you should consider adding a .htaccess file in the root of your project with just 1 line

Add the following line to your .htaccess file.

```
Options -Indexes
```